# The type scala.ScalaObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I got this error message referring to producer.send() when I trying to run a kafka producer using Java Eclipse.

The error msg : " The type scala.ScalaObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files "

The code is :

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer; 
    import kafka.javaapi.producer.ProducerData;
    import kafka.message.Message;
    import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
    import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;


   public class ProducerCode {


private static Producer<String, String> producer;
private static final String topic= "mytopic";

// intialize the producer....
public void initialize() 
{
    Properties producerProps = new Properties();
    producerProps.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
    producerProps.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    producerProps.put("request.required.acks", "1");
    ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(producerProps);
    producer = new Producer<String, String>(producerConfig);
 }



public void publishMesssage() throws Exception
{            
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while (true)
{
System.out.print("Enter message to send to kafka broker (Press 'Y' to close producer): ");
  String msg = null;
  msg = reader.readLine(); // Read message from console

  //Define topic name and message
  KeyedMessage<Integer, String> keyedMsg = new KeyedMessage<Integer, String>(topic, msg);
 // producer.send(keyedMsg); // This publishes message on given topic

  //ProducerData<String, Message> producerData1 = new ProducerData<String, Message>(topic, msg.toString());
  ProducerData<String,String> the_msg = new ProducerData<String,String>(topic,msg);
  producer.send(the_msg);
  producer.close();


  if("Y".equals(msg)){ break; }
  System.out.println("--> Message [" + msg + "] sent.Check message on Consumer's program console");
 } // end while

return;

   }// end publishMesssage







public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ProducerCode kafkaProducer = new ProducerCode();

    // Initialize producer
    kafkaProducer.initialize();            

    // Publish message
    kafkaProducer.publishMesssage();

    //Close the producer
    producer.close();


}

}
```

how I can solve this problem to send a message from the producer.

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing: your project setup does **not** contain all the JARs that the Kafka tooling expects you to have in your classpath. In other words: read the kafka documentation about the required setup for JARs, classpath, ... and then fix your eclipse project setup.

Comment: I have added these external JARs: kafka_2.8.2-0.8.0-beta1.jar
kafka_2.10-0.8.0-beta1-sources.jar
kafka_2.10-0.8.0-beta1.jar
kafka-0.05.jar
kafka-0.6.jar
kafka-0.7.0 2.jar
kafka-0.7.0.jar
kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar
kafka-perf_2.9.2-0.8.0-beta1-sources 2.jar
kafka-perf_2.9.2-0.8.0-beta1-sources.jar
kafka-perf_2.9.2-0.8.0-beta1.jar

Comment: Side note:you never put more infos into comments; update your question instead.